# Unable to move Sprite

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm unable to move the sprite even after I set the class on the Sprite in the GameScene. Below is my code for the GameplayScene class. I did not include my Player class because the code is really basic. (just a movePlayer bool function with a if statement that moves based on the x position)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameplayScene: SKScene {


var player: Player? // created new varible player for the scene, inherited the player class

var canMove = false // created new varible for letting player move; false by default

var moveLeft = false // created new varible to move player left; false by default

var center: CGFloat? // created new varible to set center of screen


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    center = (self.scene?.size.width)! / (self.scene?.size.height)! //calculates center of screen

    player.self?.childNodeWithName("Player") as? Player! // adds node "Player" within Player class(Player!)

}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    managePlayer() //constantly checks if player can/is moving

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self) // gets location inside scene

        if location.x > center {  // if statement to check if user to taping screen on the right

            moveLeft = false //moves player right

        } else {

            moveLeft = true

        }
    }

    canMove = true 

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    canMove = false //says if player is not touching screen, the player will not move
}

func managePlayer() {

    if canMove {

        player?.movePlayer(moveLeft) //takes the Player varible(which has the class), then grabs the move player func, then checks argument moveLeft
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Ran it through the debugger and it said player = (JackTheGiant.Player?) nil

Answer (score 0):

add player = self.childNode(withName: "Player") as? Player to func didMove in GameplayScene.swift

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("didmove")

        center = (self.scene?.size.width)! / (self.scene?.size.height)!
        player = self.childNode(withName: "Player") as? Player
    }
```